# Deserialize using a function of the tag

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

An API with this internally tagged field structure, with "topic" being the tag:

```json
{
    "topic": "Car"
    "name": "BMW"
    "HP": 250
}
```

This can be deserialized with

```rs
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "topic")]
pub enum catalog {
    CarEntry(Car),
    ... (other types)
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Car {
    pub name: String
    pub HP: i32
}
```

It turns out that instead of reporting the topic as just `Car`, the API actually sends `Car.product1` or `Car.product2` etc.

This breaks the deserialization, because the deserializer doesn't know what the type is based on the string. Is there a way to supply a function to chop off the type string so that the correct model is found?

Comment: "It turns out that instead of reporting the topic as just "Car", the API actually sends "Car.product1" or "Car.product2" etc." be more clear this is the contrary of the beginning of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think serde provides a way to mangle the tag before using it (at least I don't see anything [relevant](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html)). And the generated serializers for tagged enums are relatively complex, with internal caching if the tag isn't the first field, and whatnot, so I wouldn't want to reproduce that in a custom deserializer.

The cheapest (but not necessarily most efficient) shot at this is to deserialize to `serde_json::Value` first, manually process the tag, and then deserialize the `serde_json::Value`s to whatever struct you want.

Do that in a custom deserializer, and it starts looking reasonable:

```rust
impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Catalog {
    fn deserialize<D>(d: D) -> Result<Self, <D as Deserializer<'de>>::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        use serde_json::{Map, Value};
        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        struct Pre {
            topic: String,
            #[serde(flatten)]
            data: Map<String, Value>,
        }
        let v = Pre::deserialize(d)?;
        // Now you can mangle Pre any way you want to get your final structs.
        match v.topic.as_bytes() {
            [b'C', b'a', b'r', b'.', _rest @ ..] => Ok(Catalog::CarEntry(
                serde_json::from_value(v.data.into()).map_err(de::Error::custom)?,
            )),
            [b'B', b'a', b'r', b'.', _rest @ ..] => Ok(Catalog::BarEntry(
                serde_json::from_value(v.data.into()).map_err(de::Error::custom)?,
            )),
            _ => return Err(de::Error::unknown_variant(&v.topic, &["Car.…", "Bar.…"])),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=088d0c3a99025756c5a7fa5b31136e32)

Btw, what do you want to do with the suffix of `topic`? Throw it away? How do you plan on handling serialization if you do throw it away?

Comment: The suffix is basically a subtopic, but it's repeated elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

#### You can directly use `enum` instead of defining extra struct type.

```rs
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "topic")]
pub enum Catalog {
    Car { name: String, hp: i32 }
}

fn main() {
    let car = Catalog::Car { name: String::from("BMW"), hp: 2000 };

    // Convert the Car to a JSON string.
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&car).unwrap();

    // Prints serialized = {"topic":"Car","name":"BMW","hp":2000}
    println!("serialized = {}", serialized);

    // Convert the JSON string back to a Car.
    let deserialized: Catalog = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();

    // Prints deserialized = Car { name: "BMW", hp: 2000 }
    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

[`Playground`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7f68a16bda2a50dc60e63a3c50423092)

---

#### You can use [`#[serde(rename()]`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#rename) to rename type in output

```rs
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(tag = "topic")]
pub enum Catalog {
    #[serde(rename(serialize = "Car", deserialize = "CarEntry"))]
    CarEntry(Car),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Car {
    pub name: String,
    pub hp: i32
}

fn main() {
    let car = Car { name: String::from("BMW"), hp: 2000 };
    let catalog = Catalog::CarEntry(car);
    // Convert the Car to a JSON string.
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&catalog).unwrap();

    // Prints serialized = {"topic":"Car","name":"BMW","hp":2000}
    println!("serialized = {}", serialized);

    // Convert the JSON string back to a Car.
    let deserialized: Car = serde_json::from_str(&serialized).unwrap();

    // Prints deserialized = Car { name: "BMW", hp: 2000 }
    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);
}
```

[`Playground`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1b3b79fa8c93d185c857cf70c9b78637)